# Yargs.argv is always [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js, yargs

Ubuntu 16.04. I'm doing a node.js course on Udemy. I tried it with the exact version the instructor was using, then I upgraded to the latest(11.0.0). Both gave the same output.

```
const yargs = require('yargs');

var argv = yargs.argv;

console.log("yargs : " + argv);
```

I run it on the console with

```
node app.js jdskl jkdlsfj
```

console output is

```
yargs : [object Object]
```

As I understand it, it should have my args in there.

Comment: try `console.log("yargs : ", argv);` the `+` concatenates the string, the `,` passes argv as a separate argument to console log which should trigger a separate log format

Comment: the other option is: `console.log("yargs : " + JSON.stringify(argv));` as this will serialize your object into a JSON string representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `console.log("yargs : ", argv);`

The `+` concatenates the string, the `,` passes argv as a separate argument to console log which should trigger a separate log format

---

The other option is: `console.log("yargs : " + JSON.stringify(argv));` as this will serialize your object into a JSON string representation

Comment: console.log(argv);
console.dir(argv);
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(argv)));  all work for me.  The last does not transform the command line keys into strings.  For the other two just avoid a string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
const yargs = require("yargs");
console.log((JSON.stringify(yargs.argv)));
```

CMD:

```
node app.js add --title="This is a test"
Result: {
         "_":["add"],
         "title":"This is a test",
         "$0":"app.js"
        }
```